# Search Delete using csv.reader in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to search a column and delete from csv file using python. I cannot dataframes as I need to work with large files and can't load it in RAM. How to do it?
example csv file-

```
Home,Contact,Adress
abc,123,xyz
```

I need to find and delete Contact for example. I thought to use csv.reader but cannot figure out how to do it

Comment: Is creating a new csv file with removed column an option for you ?

Comment: Ya I actually did that way only but was thinking if there is any other way also, you know just in case

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "editing" option on the fly, you have to either load it into memory with pandas for example, change the dataframe then write it back or iterating over the lines, do the editing then write in another file line by line (As I showed in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
import csv

col = 'Contact'

with open('your_csv.csv') as f:
    with open('new_csv.csv', 'w', newline='') as g:
        
        # creating csv reader
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        # getting the 'col' index in the header, we want to delete it in the next lines
        col_index = next(reader).index(col)

        for line in reader:
            del line[col_index]

            # writing to new csv file
            writer = csv.writer(g)
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Explanation for using `newline=''` is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3).

Answer (score 0):

If your application prefers to work with pandas still, I'd suggest to play with pandas chunking tactic. See example below:

```
iterator = pandas.read_csv('/tmp/abc.csv', chunksize=10**5)
df_new = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['your_remaining_columns'])

for df in iterator:
    del df['col_b']
    df_new = pandas.concat([df_new, df])

print(df_new.shape[0])
print(df_new.columns)
```

I was able to process a 50GB csv file with complex data (non utf8 encoding, cell contains `,`, doing deduplication and filtered out bad rows) by this approach before.

Comment: Do you think that the csv module cannot handle weird characters?

Comment: We can try to check it. But the case is also related to big file processing. I think we could, in someway, to play with csv module, but it shall be more complicated.

Comment: You are right on one point: Pandas makes handling of data sets easier. But it comes to the price of a very large library and a syntax which is inconsistant with the core of Python. On the other end, the `csv` module nicely handles **any** csv file (even if rows have different length) and is included in the standard library. But it requires more boiling platter code... Long story short, for heavy dataframe usage, Pandas is definitely worth it, but for casual uses, the `csv` module is an excellent tool.

Comment: I agree, actually I just make a test and found the csv tool doesn't have any issue with handling complex cell with value such as `valx,val2\r\n abc,1234`. It's potentially a mistake when I recalled my exp working with CSV from the linux util. Let me update the original answer. Thanks bro.